# On Windows, how can a user batch resize AND preserve star ratings in the resized photos?

Tags: tablet

This is related to this prior question: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/39320/how-to-copy-pictures-with-3-stars-to-tablet-preserving-folder-structure-using-f

The goal is to move thousands of pictures and folders to a tablet.

On windows, using free tools only, a user may  create a copy of 100+ folders with 5000+pictures, pruned those that have less then 3 starts using a search in win explorer (rating <3 stars), and is there software that batch resizes and preserves star rating?

FastStone Photo Resizer is very smart in resizing: resize based on short side (to be exactly 768)   (for tablet viewing)  (handles 16:9 and 4:3 well !), HOWEVER, it does not preserve star rating.....

is there a free software that preserves stars and is a smart batch resizer?

Answer (score 2):

yup, moving away from photography here... Just use http://www.fotosizer.com/ should batch resize while maintaining all metadata... i only use fs resizer for pics I put up on facebook, which it strips of metadata anyways...

Comment: btw... if you figure out the options fotosizer offers you'll be able to maintain your folder structure... make sure to select the root folder (click include sub-folder). make sure to select to "duplicate the source image folders". You'll probably also want to reverse width and height by orientation....

Comment: FotoSizer does copy some data (EXIF), however the star ratings (used by XnViewMP or Win Live Photo Gallery, [XMP, IPTC]) are NOT PRESERVED by that program when converted.